# Opening a simulink model and changing parameters of a component in the model

Tags: simulink

I have a simulink model M where there is a "From Workspace" type component
named "input" in M. From command line, I want to open model M, and then set
"Data" and "Sample time" values to my user-defined values.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the function `set_param`, which has the general syntax

```
set_param('ModelName/BlockName','BlockProperty','NewValue');
```

Note the first input is the block name, not type, so if your block is called called 'From Workspace' then you want,

```
set_param('ModelName/From Workspace','VariableName','NewMATLABVariableName',...
   'SampleTime','NewSampleTimeAsAString');
```

Further notes

1. If your block name is split over 2 lines then you also need to include the carriage return in the block name, so you need

   `set_param(['ModelName/From',char(10),'Workspace'],'VariableName',...
        'NewMATLABVariableName','SampleTime','NewSampleTimeAsAString');`
2. All parameters are set as strings so you may need to use `num2str` to convert a numeric time to a string representation.
3. The above assumes that the model is open.  If it is not then you either need to open it using `open_system('YourModelName');` or `load_model('YourModelName');` to load it into memory.